# Graphene GraphiQL does not work in browsers, but Insomnia client works just fine

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm a beginner in GraphQL and have been doing some tutorials and simple projects with it. Today I was following a new tutorial and ran into something odd. The GraphiQL interface from graphene_django will not return anything in browsers. I get a different error in every browser:

(Chrome)

```
Cannot read property '1' of null
```

(Firefox)

```
match is null
```

(Safari)

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'match[1]')
```

However, in Insomnia, everything works just fine.

I would guess my code works fine since I am getting a response in Insomnia, but my browser just won't let me play. Does anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just installed `graphene-django` then check its version, if it's **2.12.0** then downgrade to version **2.11.1** and it will work perfectly.

Looks like there is an issue with **2.12.0**

As a temporary workaround, you can give your query a name (check github [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/1003#issuecomment-657738053)):

```
query my_query{
   type{
      field
   }
}
```